# How to split a single spread sheet with 20 tabs into separate sheets（different files）

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a single spreadsheet with 20 tabs but it's become very heavy to handle so I would like to split it into different sheets （files）

If it's possible, could you possibly suggest some Google Apps Scripts so that I can manage to do it?

Hopefully, a tab name becomes the name of the new file when convert.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that should work. The `toFolderName` is blank by default, so your files will be saved to your root folder. If you put a unique folder name in, the files will be copied to that folder. I suggest to start here, it is a pretty slow script though, 20 tabs should take a little over a minute.

```
function migrateSheetsToFiles() {
  var mySheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var toFolderName = '';
  var i;
  for(i in mySheets){
    var currentSheet = mySheets[i];
    var oldData = currentSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create(currentSheet.getName());
    var newId = newFile.getId();
    var newSheet = newFile.getSheets()[0]

    newSheet.getRange(1,1,oldData.length,oldData[0].length).setValues(oldData);
    newSheet.setName(newFile.getName());

    if(toFolderName != ''){
      var fileInDrive = DriveApp.getFileById(newId);
      fileInDrive.makeCopy(fileInDrive.getName(),DriveApp.getFoldersByName(toFolderName).next());
      fileInDrive.setTrashed(true);
    };

  };
};
```

Comment: I’m sorry that i haven’t replied for ages and you helped me a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Make the answer correct if it is what you were looking for. Thanks