# Copy and apply conditional formatting while creating separate spreadsheets from multiple tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, format, conditional-formatting

I'm using the code in the following post ([How to split a single spread sheet with 20 tabs into separate sheets（different files）](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420757/how-to-split-a-single-spread-sheet-with-20-tabs-into-separate-sheets-different-f)) to create separate documents from a single spreadsheet that has multiple tabs/sheets.

This has been relatively successful, but I have not been able to copy the formatting, neither the cell width and height nor the two conditional formatting rules in cell C2. To this aim I used the code in this post:

[Google script to copy sheet in spreadsheet to new spreadsheet and name new spreadsheet after specific cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744372/google-script-to-copy-sheet-in-spreadsheet-to-new-spreadsheet-and-name-new-sprea)

Unfortunately, that code only copies values and not formulas.

I've attempted to use code from this port, to no avail:

[Script: How to copy and reapply conditional formatting rules to a range on edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814849/script-how-to-copy-and-reapply-conditional-formatting-rules-to-a-range-on-edit)

Is it possible to copy and apply conditional formatting while creating separate spreadsheets from multiple tabs?

This is mu current code:

```
function migrateSheetsToFiles() {
  var mySheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var toFolderName = 'ScreenerUserFolder';
  var i;
  for(i in mySheets){
    var currentSheet = mySheets[i];
    var oldData = currentSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var oldDataFormula = currentSheet.getRange("A2").getFormula();
    var oldDataFormatting = currentSheet.getRange("C2").getFormula();    
    var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create(currentSheet.getName());
    var newId = newFile.getId();
    var newSheet = newFile.getSheets()[0]
    newSheet.getRange(1,1,oldData.length,oldData[0].length).setValues(oldData);
    newSheet.getRange(2,1,oldData.length,oldData[0].length).setFormula(oldDataFormula);
    newSheet.deleteRow(4).deleteColumn(3).deleteRow(3).deleteColumn(2);
    newSheet.setName(newFile.getName());
    if(toFolderName != ''){
      var fileInDrive = DriveApp.getFileById(newId);
      fileInDrive.makeCopy(fileInDrive.getName(),DriveApp.getFoldersByName(toFolderName).next());
      fileInDrive.setTrashed(true);
    };

  };
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the issue of your current script? And, can I ask you about the detail of `no avail` of `I've attempted to use code from this port, to no avail: Script: How to copy and reapply conditional formatting rules to a range on edit?`?

Comment: Of course, thank you very much. With my current script I currently get the desired result of individual files from the tabs on an original spreadsheet. However, the number of columns and rows does not remain the same as each original tab, nor does the width and height of the columns/rows and the conditional formatting isn't copied onto the new documents. On attempting to use the code from the mentioned post, and probably due to my lack of experience, I have not been able to copy the conditional formatting. If you have any insight about this I'd most grateful.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, can I ask you about the difference between your goal and to directly copy the Google Spreadsheet including the sheets?

Comment: Of course. Once again, thank you.
Source file for documents to be copied from:
<https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HOV_ZamCwEDlqxgFfVk3mWQeBF7mD4UCVm8wVV90kZE/edit#gid=847443505>
Source Folder:
<https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b4YlzJp3OdYo9ZilipDw-IOn9TM-Zy1w?usp=sharing>

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your question. For example, in order to correctly understand about it, can I ask you about the sample input and output Spreadsheets you expect?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try to explain this better;
1. My code is working to create new files from the tabs in my original file. This is working well.
2. The conditional formatting is not being copied. In the original file, range B:C has conditional formatting that I want to have in the new file. 
3. The original number of columns and rows is not being copied. In the original file, some tabs only have 3 columns and 6 rows. That is what I want to have in the new file. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you want to copy the sheets with all formulas and formatting - use [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

Sample:

```js
function migrateSheetsToFiles() {
  var mySheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
//  var toFolderName = 'ScreenerUserFolder';
  var i;
  for(i in mySheets){
    var currentSheet = mySheets[i];
    var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create(currentSheet.getName());
    currentSheet.copyTo(newFile);
    var newId = newFile.getId();    
    if(toFolderName != ''){
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

ATTENTION

Your source file contains within the same Apps Script project several code files with a function called `migrateSheetsToFiles()`.

Mind that you can NOT have more than one function of the same name within one Apps Script project - even if the funcitons are located in different .gs files.

I assume this is the reason that why the modifications you performed in your code did not go through.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have since renamed the surplus code files with the same name. I have copied your suggested code verbatim, but unfortunately neither the conditional formatting nor other formats have been copied.
Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: I do not have the same problem. Can you make a dummy copy of the spreadsheet and attach to it only the code I provided-deleting all other scripts and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you, that would be very kind of you, and it would be of tremendous help. My current concern is that I need the A1 =sheetName() result to be copied as text only in the new sheets. I'm certain that I have missed a relevant detail that produces the error. I would be very happy to use the sheet that you may prepare so that I might learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you managed now to copy everything with formulas and formatting? In this case, the last step is easy -you just add to the code the two lines you had before: `var newSheet = newFile.getSheets()[0] newSheet.getRange(1,1,oldData.length,oldData[0].length).setValues(oldData);` to overwrite the formula with the value manually.

Comment: Thank you. The only issue I now continue to have is that the new documents have "Copy of" in the name of the new tabs of those documents.

Comment: That's what the line `newSheet.setName(newFile.getName())` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions. Thanks to this I have proposed code and modified accordingly.

```
function migrateSheetsToFiles() {
  var mySheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var toFolderName = 'ScreenerUserFolder';
  var i;
  for(i in mySheets){
    var currentSheet = mySheets[i];
    var newFile = SpreadsheetApp.create(currentSheet.getName());
        var newId = newFile.getId();
           currentSheet.copyTo(newFile);
    var source = newFile.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
        newFile.deleteSheet(source);
    if(toFolderName != ''){
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rooBctI9qRbcpQSIR79S76xMSJchSmK4");
        files.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
      files.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      var oldData = currentSheet.getRange('a1').getValues();
        newFile.getRange('a1').setValues(oldData);
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rooBctI9qRbcpQSIR79S76xMSJchSmK4");
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newId);
        file.moveTo(targetFolder);  
};
}
}
```